# datetimepicker bootstrap eonasdan

Tags: javascript, datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I need to get the changed value in the datetimepicker.
I tried

```
   $('#startDate').datetimepicker().on('dp.change', function (event) {
      console.log(event.date);
   });
```

And :

```
   $('#startDate').datetimepicker().on('dp.hide', function (event) {
      console.log(event.date);
   });
```

But the result is the value before the change.

Help me to understand please.

Comment: you read the docs? http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Events/#dpchange

Comment: in the docs "dp.change : Fired when the date is changed."  In my browser the event is fired when i click on the glypicon, and i take the old date.

Comment: When i really changed the date nothing is happened.

Answer (score 0):

i think this is what you want (just edit the `$('input')` with your element ID or class name:
https://jsfiddle.net/yqgxd472/

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class='col-sm-6'>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
          <input type='text' class="form-control" />
          <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

js:

```
 $(function() {
   $('input').datetimepicker({
   format: 'YYYY-MM-DD H:m:s'
   });
 });

 $('input').datetimepicker().on('dp.change', function(event) {
   console.log(moment(event.date).format('YYYY-MM-DD')); // using moment.js
 });
```